# weaviate aggregate by reference property

Tags: weaviate

I want to build an aggregate query on my data.
I have Patents class that have references of Paragraphs classes (paragraphs that have vectorized text),
I want to count patents for each catagory (property of patent) that are near vector.

in psuedo SQL:

```
select (count distinct Patent)
from myweaviate
where Paragraph.nearVector(vector, certainty=0.9)
group by catagory
```

I tried using something like (which is also bad even if it worked because it counts paragraphs):

```html
result = (client.query.aggregate("Paragraph") \
    .with_group_by_filter(["inPatent{... on Patent{publicationID}"]) \
    .with_fields('meta { count }') \
    .with_fields('groupedBy {value}') \
    .with_near_vector({'vector': vector, 'certainty': 0.8}) \
    .do())
```

and getting:

```
{'data': {'Aggregate': {'Paragraph': None}}, 'errors': [{'locations': [{'column': 12, 'line': 1}], 'message': "could not extract groupBy path: Expected a valid property name in 'path' field for the filter, but got 'inPatent{... on Patent{publicationID}'", 'path': ['Aggregate', 'Paragraph']}]}
```

I couldn't find any source in the docs or in the internet to do something like that, (aka use aggregate on reference property),
additionally, doing a count distinct (but in this case the Patent class is distinct of course)
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it is not possible to do grouping by cross-references. The error in your case means that you did not construct a valid `path`, that is because the `path` needs to be a list where each item is a valid configuration, i.e. the path should be like this: `path: ["inPatent", "Patent", "publicationID"]`. It goes `property -> class name -> property -> class name -> ...` til your desired field. Currently Weaviate does not support `Aggregate.groupBy` with cross references, if you run your query again with the correct `path` you should get something like this:

```
"message": "shard 9wKKa18SJOiM: identify groups: grouping by cross-refs not supported"
```

Note that it is possible to use the cross reference property as your `groupBy` `path` (since you want to Aggregate on the Patent ID, it means that the UUID (and beacon) of the Patent object are unique has a one-to-one mapping to the `publicationID` ), and it should look like this:

```py
result = (client.query.aggregate("Paragraph") \
    .with_group_by_filter(["inPatent"]) \
    .with_fields('meta { count }') \
    .with_fields('groupedBy {value}') \
    .with_near_vector({'vector': vector, 'certainty': 0.8}) \
    .do())
```